# trouble with boolean value used as switch for showing or not in my view

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

It must be an understanding typo issue. I have a recordset which I use for initializing during import data.
I don't want to show the special record in my views.

My database with the record looks like follows:

[image: record in database]

In my method I tried to add a where statement:

The type is tinyint.

```
public function fetchAllP($projectid)
{
    $show = 0;
    return $this->tableGateway->select(['ProjectID' => $projectid],['show_not' => false]);
}
```

As you can see I tried with false/0 whatever. Anyway the method works without the show_not equation.

Where is my error? It should be quite simle, but I won't see the mistake and the record is still shown. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
return $this->tableGateway->select(['ProjectID' => $projectid, 'show_not' => false]);
```

The `select`method accepts only one parameter.